# magento 2 javascript how to getCustomerData

Tags: javascript, magento2

I want to display some custom information in minicard based on customerData. So i found minicard.js copy in proper child theme location.

Now to get customer data i use `'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'` witch is alredy in minicard.js.

inside of `initialize` function I run code like so:

```
        var customer = customerData.get('customer');
        console.log('customer', customer().firstName);
```

This returns undefined on every page. However On checkout page i can get customerData simply call `window.customerData`. So question is how can I get customerData on every page and why now even on my checkout page `customerData.get('customer');` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> 'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'

like this example to get Firstname + Lastname

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
], function ($, Component, customer) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        customerData: customer.customerData,

        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/customer-information'
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isVisible: function () {
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * @return {String}
         */
        getFullName: function () {
            return this.customerData.firstname + ' ' + this.customerData.lastname;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I solved by creating custom section in customer data. Than i load it by `customerSection.get('name)`